# Run code from server n Xcode

Tags: xcode, get

I'm trying to build a iPhone/iPad app that can get code from my server when a button is pushed. Something like:

```
-(IBAction)getCode:(id)sender
{

// get code from server

}
```

I've researched and haven't found anything.  I'm not sure if this is possible but it would be very helpful thank you.

Comment: You are planning to execute the code or just to display it?

Answer (score 0):

I use [RestKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki). It is awesome, especially if your server is Restful. If not, you can just do get's and post's with RKClient.

Answer (score 0):

See 'URL Loading System Programming Guide' from the Apple iOS 5.1 documentation.